# Gauss law and electric flux

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Can you please explain me what is electric flux. I know it is $\int\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$, but in many place its given flux means to flow. But how does electric field "flow"? Also if we assume its the electric field lines (can you also specify what exactly are these) are "flowing" how does $\int\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$ give the total electric field lines passing through that area? (can you please elaborate when you explain?)

Pls. I know it shouldn't come here but there is no page for electric flux.

Comment: How do positive test charges flow if you put them in that electric field?

Comment: On my opinion, a professional-style communication should be highly encouraged there, what includes the correct usage of the punctuations and markups. The main problem is with such a post as yours, if it is visible that you are lazy to press the shift key, probably you won't read and understand the answers what you get.

Comment: Have you done any research so far? What do you mean by "no page for electric flux"?

Comment: In this case, flux does not mean flow.  Electric flux and velocity fields have a lot in common, but there's one important aspect that they do not share:  water flows, electric fields don't.

Comment: Duplicated a number of times over?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70751/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225556/ amongst others.

Comment: *"there is no page for electric flux"* it literally takes 1 second Google search.

Comment: You have a few things in your question that reveal misunderstanding. First of all the "flux" does not require a closed surface.  This is special to Gauss' law but Flux is defined for any vector (field) and any surface element (open or closed).  I get the feeling that you need to review flux as a mathematical concept before getting specific to electric flux.

Answer (score -1):

The concept of electric 'flux' is not strictly related to something flowing through an area, like for example, fluid flux which involved flow of fluid through an area.  But the concept of electric flux is still very useful. One example where it is useful is:

Suppose you have an isolated body with an unknown charge distribution in vacuum and you want to find out what the total charge on the body is.  It turns out that you can find the total charge without even having to physically touch the body.

Imagine the body being enclosed by an imaginary sphere of radius $r$.  Divide the surface of the sphere into $N$ equal areas $A$.  Take a test charge $q$ and measure the force $F_i$ that it experiences when placed on each of the regions of $N$ surfaces. Then add up the products $\frac{F_i }{q}A$. This will give you the total flux.

One of Maxwell's equations tells us that this total flux is equal to $\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$ where $Q$ is the charge of the body we started with and $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of free space.  Therefore, you can find $Q$.

Its better to think of electric field lines are being simply a mathematical tool which tells us in which direction the force acting on a positive test charge will act when another charged particle is present.  They are perpendicular to lines of equal electric potential.  If you are familiar with fluid mechanics, electric fields are mathematically analogous to velocity fields and electric potential is mathematically analogous to velocity potential.

You often hear the phrase "there are more field lines because the charge is larger".  This can be confusing.  Technically, field lines are everywhere around a charge.  They are at every single point around the charge.  When you see the phrase "more field lines", it just means that the force acting on a test particle which is placed in the field, will be larger in magnitude.  You can think of the density of field lines as being represented as different shades of colours (instead of number of lines) around a charged particle, with darker colour shades corresponding to higher density of field lines.

Comment: Why was this down voted?  It is a good answer and reveals things that people misunderstand about "flow" versus flux in general.